# Why distributed AG is preferred to normal AG for cross datacenter failover scenario?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, disaster-recovery, distributed-availability-groups

I have two node WSFC and currently I'm working on DR solution with availability group.I already read microsoft doc about distributed AG.So  my question is what are benefits of using distributed AG compared to normal AG? Can we just stretch WSFC across data center and make this happen with normal AG?

Answer (score 2):

> what are benefits of using distributed AG compared to normal AG?

Complete isolation of your clusters is the only benefit.

> Can we just stretch WSFC across data center and make this happen with normal AG?

Yes, and you normally should do just that.  Stretch clusters are not complicated, and modern versions of Windows make them downright simple.  IE the cluster node voting configuration and quorum is pretty much automatic.  And you can even implement automatic cross-datacenter fail-over with [Cloud Witness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/deploy-cloud-witness).

Comment: Distributed AG is more for scenario where you have multiple node on a distant site. Instead of synchronizing them all from the distant site, you sync 1 node and use that node to sync the other node from that site.
Ex : Site 1 in US with 3 nodes and site 2 in China with 3 nodes. Normal AG will have to replicate all transaction from Active node on site 1 to the other 2 nodes in site 1 (ok) but also to all the other node of site 2. With a distributed AG, it will sync all node from site 1 and only 1 node from Site 2 then the other Ag on Site 2 will replicate to the other nodes in Site 2.